# Interface generated by code or xml in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, performance, user-interface

Which way of building interface gives more performance in Android: by java code or by xml layout file?

Comment: Performance-wise: by java code.

Comment: Don't let the microseconds you're going to save by coding your layouts in Java sway your decision from using the XML layouts.  They are by far better and easier to use.  Even for simple components, I'll create a layout, inflate it and add it to the view.  Styles also can't be added to components created dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to measure, the question is more about convenience and code maintenance.

The great advantage of XML generated layouts is that your application logic and code not have dependency from a UI, your app visual design. Because, after some time, the logic may stay the same, but Visual design can change (for example - migration to new [Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html)). It is good at POV of [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). Also, another people, like designers, can change your XML view, without interacting your code. 

From my expirience, it is no difference of performance when using code generated layouts. Again, it is all about convenience - you can dinamically add elements, change it parameters, and other things on runtime, that XML layout can't provide. 

You must make your decision, which to use, based of the goals that you are trying to achieve.

TL;DR; There are not serious difference of performance, IMHO.

Comment: OK! Thank you for comment. There are any applications to measure android app performance?

Comment: Yeah, there are build in SDK KIT tools, that can measure your app performance, you can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html), and look how to use it [here](https://youtu.be/AJVolvNwHL8?t=8m30s).

Comment: That is what I want! Tanks a lot again.